# help parsing values using perl regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I'm stuck trying to figure out the perl regex to extract the following values: (the /home/mail/dump dirs will always be the same). Thanks.

`abc`

`123456`

This is the output:

```
drwxr-xr-x   - mail_hd mail_users          0 2011-03-26 20:12 /home/mail/dump/abc
drwxr-xr-x   - mail_hd mail_users          0 2011-04-15 09:10 /home/mail/dump/123456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599763/help-using-command-line-to-extract-snippets-of-data-on-stdout/5602015#5602015)

Split on "/" and get the last item

```
awk -F"/" '{print $NF}' file
```

Ruby(1.9+) (similar for Perl)

```
$ ruby -ne 'print $_.sub(/.*\//,"")' file
abc
123456

$ ruby -F"/" -ane 'print $F[-1]' file
abc
123456
```

Comment: Since the OP asked for Perl, `perl -F/ -lane'print $F[-1]' file`

Comment: @ikegami. you should supply that as an answer.

Comment: thanks guys, these are all good answers. its cool to see the other versions. i'll go with these.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) and [`basename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html), instead.

Comment: `use File::Basename qw( basename ); basename((split(' ', $_, 8))[-1])`

Answer (score 1):

The following perl regex will give just the characters after the final forward slash.

```
s=.*/==
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'wxr-xr-x   - mail_hd mail_users          0 2011-03-16 18:46 /home/mail/dump/abc' | perl -pe 's=.*/=='
abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is usefull, should return what you need.

```
if ($subject =~ m!/home/mail/dump/(.*)$!) {
    $result = $1;
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

it matches everything after `/home/mail/dump/` until end of line